# Генерация сочетания k элементов из множества n

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Как можно сгенерировать случайное сочетание в JavaScript?

То есть `k` различных элементов из множества размера `n`.

(например, `k` различных чисел из множества `{1, ..., n}`)

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы сгенерировать случайное [сочетание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) размера `k` из множества размера `n` можно сделать `k` шагов, на каждом из которых:

- выбираем случайный элемент множества, используя [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- добавляем его к сочетанию
- удаляем выбранный элемент из множества

Хранить исходное множество можно как обычный массив, при этом удалению можно сделать, обменивая выбранный случайный элемент с последним элементом массива, с последующим удалением последнего элемента массива.

```js
let numberElements = 10;
let combinationSize = 6;
// для примера сгенерируем сочетание из множества {0, 1, ..., n-1}
let array = [...Array(numberElements).keys()];

let combination = [];
while (combination.length < combinationSize) {
  // выбираем случайный элемент массива и добавляем его к сочетанию
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  let randomElement = array[randomIndex];
  combination.push(randomElement);

  // удаляем выбранный элемент из массива
  array[randomIndex] = array[array.length - 1];
  array.pop();
}

// результат --- массив combination
console.log(combination)
```

В результате мы получаем массив, который, вообще говоря, упорядочен, поэтому мы получаем не сочетание, а [размещение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Но можно сказать, что порядок нам не важен (например, отсортировав массив), и получится сочетание.

Должно работать за `O(размер сочетания)`. Получающиеся сочетания имеют равномерное распределение, так как вероятность получить размещение `a_1 ... a_k` равна (`ξ_i` ­— элемент, выбранный на `i`-ом шаге)

[image: https://sharelatex.com/read/tnmhhnmmcpzg]

— зависит только от `n` и `k`, а каждому сочетанию соответствует одинаковое (`k!`) число размещений.

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от номера i выбираемого элемента, общее количество генераций в среднем равно n / (n - i), из них i / (n-i) ≈ i / n лишних.
Суммарное количество лишних генераций примерно равно (k-1)(k-2) / 2n ≈ k<sup>2</sup> / 2n.

В зависимости от соотношения k и n, можно рекомендовать различные стратегии.

1. Если k<sup>2</sup> < 2n, то генерировать индексы копируемых элементов (с проверкой повторов).
2. Если (n-k)<sup>2</sup> < 2n, то создать копию исходного массива и генерировать индексы удаляемых элементов.
3. В остальных случаях - перетасовать исходный массив (обменивая каждый элемент массива со случайно выбранным) и отобрать первые k элементов.